# EXT JS iframe to resize to height and width of containing extJS container

Tags: html, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have rendered an iframe inside an EXT JS container.As i click submit button,an iframe with source "www.totalgadha.com" is being loaded into the container.However I want the loaded page to fit to the size of container instead of having scrolls.How to resize the iframe to size of EXT JS container?
Fiddle link is:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cge

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').add({
        xtype: "component",
        width: 500,
        height: 750,
          autoEl: {
            tag: 'iframe',
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            border: '0',
            frameborder: '0',
            scrolling: 'no',
              src: 'https://www.totalgadha.com'
            }
      });
```

Comment: @Jason You should take a look at this, you may need a border layout or anchor http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

Comment: I believe you are not getting my point...since layout's won't hlep by cause......what i want is the iframe used fully fit the webpage without any scrolls...presently scrolls are present

Comment: i tried your updated code,the webpage doesn't resize to size of iframe....what happens is because of scrolling: 'no' no scrollbar appears ,so only a particular portion of web page is visible and we cannot scroll down or rigth to see remaining portion

Comment: I have made a fiddle so that it is easier to test,i tried changing the src to ""https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home"+'?abc='+abc".....in this case the rendered webpage resizes to size of iframe..........so i believe there should be some property for the webpage which resizes it to the size of the container....what's  that property?